# AngularJS Randomly Finds Module, Randomly does not, Randomly throws Error

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I didn't find a case similar to mine, but I'm just learning AngularJS so I probably am missing it. Just slap me upside the head and point me in the right direction if this was already a question. Anyways...

I made an Add User form for the work study site that I am working on, and I used AngularJS to do so. When it finds the module, it works swimmingly. Unfortunately, it finds it maybe one out of 5 times. 3 out of 5 times, I get absolutely nothing in the console. 1 out of 5 times, though, I get an AngularJS error.

```
Failed to instantiate module addUser due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/$injector/nomod?p0=addUser
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost/kushal/html/body/angular.min.js:6:416
    at http://localhost/kushal/html/body/angular.min.js:23:433
    at a (http://localhost/kushal/html/body/angular.min.js:22:483)
    at Q.bootstrap (http://localhost/kushal/html/body/angular.min.js:23:218)
    at http://localhost/kushal/html/body/angular.min.js:37:314
    at n (http://localhost/kushal/html/body/angular.min.js:7:322)
    at g (http://localhost/kushal/html/body/angular.min.js:37:92)
    at db (http://localhost/kushal/html/body/angular.min.js:40:367)
    at d (http://localhost/kushal/html/body/angular.min.js:19:219
```

I read that maybe I am using a property in my module that is not supported, but I don't know which that would be. My add_user.js file is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    (function() {
        var AddApp = angular.module('addUser', ['ngSanitize']);
        AddApp.controller('AddUserController', ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope){
            $scope.SchoolSelBox = null;
            $scope.schoolList = [];
            $scope.CitySelBox = null;
            $scope.cityList = [];
            $scope.StateSelBox = null;
            $scope.stateList = [];
            $scope.TypeSelBox = null;
            $scope.typeList = [];
            $scope.master = {};
            var original = $scope.user;
            $http.post("lib/scripts/adding_user.php", {switch_id: '1', func: 'retrieve_schools'}).
                    success(function(data) {
                        $scope.schoolList = data;
                        console.log(data);
                    }).
                    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        console.log(data, status, headers, config);
                    });
            $http.post("lib/scripts/adding_user.php", {switch_id: '1', func: 'retrieve_cities'}).
                    success(function(data) {
                        $scope.cityList = data;
                    }).
                    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        console.log(data, status, headers, config);
                    });
            $http.post("lib/scripts/adding_user.php", {switch_id: '1', func: 'retrieve_states'}).
                    success(function(data) {
                        $scope.stateList = data;
                    }).
                    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        console.log(data, status, headers, config);
                    });
            $http.post("lib/scripts/adding_user.php", {switch_id: '1', func: 'retrieve_account_types'}).
                    success(function(data) {
                        $scope.typeList = data;
                    }).
                    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        console.log(data, status, headers, config);
                    });
            $scope.addUser = function(user) {
                $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
                console.log($scope.master);
                $http.post("lib/scripts/adding_user.php", {
                    switch_id: '1', 
                    func: 'authenticate_user',
                    username: $scope.master.username,
                    email: $scope.master.email,
                    first: $scope.master.FName,
                    last: $scope.master.LName,
                    school: $scope.master.SchoolSelBox['school_id'],
                    city: $scope.master.CitySelBox['city_id'],
                    state: $scope.master.StateSelBox['state_id'],
                    account_type: $scope.master.TypeSelBox['security_level_id']
                }).
                        success(function(response){
                            console.log(response);
                            if (response.length > 1) {
                                alert('An has error occured. Please contact an administrator at stem.admin@minotstateu.edu.'); //An error not caught below
                            } else {
                                var responseArray = response.split('');
                                for (var x = 0; x < responseArray.length; x++) {
                                    switch (responseArray[x]) {
                                        case "1":
                                            $("#username_error").text("Username Already Taken");
                                            break;
                                        case "2":
                                            $("#email_error").text("*");
                                            $("#input_error").css("color", "#FF0000");
                                            $("#input_error").text("An account is already registered for this email");
                                            break;
                                        case "3":
                                            $("#input_error").css("color", "#6d962f");
                                            $("#input_error").text("Account Successfully Added");
                                            $scope.user = angular.copy(original);
                                            $scope.addUserForm.$setPristine();
                                            break;
                                        case "4":
                                            $("#input_error").css("color", "#FF0000");
                                            $("#input_error").text("Account could not be added"); //PHP error
                                            break;
                                        default:
                                            alert("add_user.js, add_user()"); //Not real sure what this does
                                            break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }).
                        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        console.log(data, status, headers, config);
                });
            };
            $scope.resetFrm = function() {
                $scope.user = angular.copy(original);
                $scope.addUserForm.$setPristine();
                $("#username_error").text("");
                $("#email_error").text("");
                $("#input_error").text("");
            };
        }]);
    })();
});
```

I don't know if you will need the HTML for this or not, so here is add_user.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (($_SESSION['sec_level']) != 4) {
    header("Location: permission_error.php");
}
include "lib/header/header.php";
include "lib/linklib.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="addUser">
    <head>
        <title>Add User</title>
        <?php
        csslib();
        jslib();
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/add_user.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body >
    <center><div id="bordercontainer">  
            <?php
            headermenu();
            ?>
            <div id="maincontainer">
                <br />    
                <span class="header headerTextAlignment">Add User</span>
                <br />
                <center>
                    <br />
                    <div id="addusercontainer">
                        <form name="addUserForm" novalidate ng-controller="AddUserController as addUserCtrl" ng-submit="addUserForm.$valid && addUser(user)"> 
                            <!--Checks to see if the form is valid before submission using the $valid form controller. AND statement. ng = Angular JS -->
                            <div class="row-fluid">
                                <span class="adduser_heading">Username:</span>
                                <input type="text" id="username" class="adduser_input" size="35" ng-model="user.username" required ng-pattern="string"/>
                                <span class="adduser_error" id="username_error"></span>
                            </div>  
                            <div class="row-fluid">
                                <span class="adduser_heading">Email:</span>
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="adduser_input" size="35" ng-model="user.email" required ng-pattern="string"/>
                                <span class="adduser_error" id="email_error"></span>
                            </div>  
                            <div class="row-fluid">
                                <span class="adduser_heading">Confirm Email:</span>
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="confirm_email" class="adduser_input" size="35" ng-model="user.ConfEmail" required ng-pattern="string"/>
                                <span class="adduser_error" id="match_error"></span>
                            </div>  
                            <div class="row-fluid">
                                <span class="adduser_heading">First Name:</span>
                                <input type="text" id="first" class="adduser_input" size="35" ng-model="user.FName" required ng-pattern="string"/>
                                <span class="adduser_error" id="first_error"></span>
                            </div>  
                            <div class="row-fluid">
                                <span class="adduser_heading">Last name:</span>
                                <input type="text" id="last" class="adduser_input" size="35" ng-model="user.LName" required ng-pattern="string"/>
                                <span class="adduser_error" id="last_error"></span>
                            </div>  
                            <div class="row-fluid">
                                <span class="adduser_heading">School:</span>
                                <select ng-model="user.SchoolSelBox" ng-options="name.school_name for (key, name) in schoolList" id="school" class="adduser_input" style="width: 264px;" required></select>
                            </div>  
                            <div class="row-fluid">
                                <span class="adduser_heading">City:</span>
                                <select ng-model="user.CitySelBox" id="city" class="adduser_input" style="width: 264px;" ng-options="name.city_name for (key, name) in cityList" required></select>
                            </div>  
                            <div class="row-fluid">
                                <span class="adduser_heading">States:</span>
                                <select ng-model="user.StateSelBox" id="state" class="adduser_input" style="width: 264px;" ng-options="name.state_name for (key, name) in stateList" required></select>         
                            </div>  
                            <div class="row-fluid">
                                <span class="adduser_heading">Account Type:</span>
                                <select ng-model="user.TypeSelBox" id="account_type" class="adduser_input" style="width: 264px;" ng-options="name.security_level_type for (key, name) in typeList" required></select>
                            </div>  
                            <div class="row-fluid">
                                <div class="adduser_button_left">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" >Reset</button>
                                </div>
                                <span class="adduser_large_error" id="input_error"></span>
                                <div class="adduser_button_right">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" value="Submit" >Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                </center>
                <!--  Load Modal -->
                <div id="loadModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="progress">
                            <div class="bar" style="width: 0%; " data-percentage="100" ></div>
                        </div>
                        <span id="comment"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>                          
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I do have Angular JS and ngSanitize included in that lib/linklib.php file. All those console.log()'s are there for feedback. The JS goes to PHP back-end code which interacts with the database. If you need any more information, I will try and get it up asap. Just a bit stumped since it seems to be happening 1/5 times.

Oh, this is through localhost. I have my own copy of the code and the database, so I am not going through a firewall or gateway or anything like that to access the database. Don't know if that matters, just tossing it out there.

Thanks.

Edit: Should probably mention what happens when it does not work. The HTML loads just fine, but the select boxes do not populate. Clicking the Submit and Reset button don't do anything.

Comment: First I would remove the jQuery $(document).ready piece of code and see if that helps.

Comment: It's worth noting if you are new to Angular that modules break easily due to errors in syntax and such inside them. What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: First thing I'd do is switch to the un-minified version of Angular. The error messages are more verbose

Comment: Huh. Works every time now. I'm guessing switching from minified to un-minified did not fix it, so it must have been the document.ready I added. I can't remember my logic at the time for adding it, but it must have made sense to me at the time. Well, great then, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I removed the jQuery $(document).ready, as per o4ohel's suggesstion, and it works swimmingly and consistently now. Thanks!